# What is the name for this type of anchor bolt with a "leg"?

Tags: bolts

I'm trying to figure out what this is called. This was used in a basketball hoop to connect a piece of square bar to a flat metal frame. The bolt went through the metal frame, then into a hole in the metal square bar. When tightened, as you'd expect, it snugly secured the frame to the square bar.

It's frustrating because I'm not sure what to call this thing. It has a "leg" that's a little different than J-bolts or the 90-degree anchor bolts that I've seen advertised.

Any ideas on what I should refer to it as? Also, is this a "standard" bolt or is this some weird one-off thing that no one else uses?

[image: some sort of anchor bolt]

Comment: I suspect weird one-off - similar in concept, but not scale, to a concrete anchor bolt.

Answer (score 2):

This is a specialty bolt made up my the manufacturer of the basketball hoop. I suspect you are asking because you need a new one. I doubt if you will be able to find one, but you should be able to make up something very similar that will do the same function. Get a regular bolt, washer and nut, with the right diameter and length. A second washer might be good enough to sandwich in the the square bar to the frame. If not, get a small plate and drill a hole in it for the bolt. The plate will serve the same purpose as the "leg" on the existing bolt.

Answer (score 1):

According to a manufacturer ([constructiontool.com](http://www.constructiontool.com/?s=Right%20Angled%20Bend%20Anchor%20Bolts)), they're **Right Angled Bend Anchor Bolts**. I agree with @Larry, that they were special order.

---

> This is a steel bolt, with 1/4-20 threads on one end and a bent shaft on the other.
>   Anchor Bolt, 1/4-20, 1.875" long, steel: ([andymark.com](http://www.andymark.com/product-p/am-1267.htm))

[image]

Used to avoid through bolting for esthetics or for where it's inaccessible. The one pictured would need a few washers so you don't run out of threads.

I'd just use a longer bolt: drill a hole on the opposite side of the tube and through bolt it.